# Selenium webdriver error for chromedriver and chrome version

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run integration test of a Rails application in Mac. But I am getting the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77
```

When I run `chromedriver --version`, I get this output: `ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882})`

So I have a higher version of chromedriver installed in my system. Chrome version is `80`.

But why is selenium showing the above error? Should I download chrome version 77 to rectify it or can I specify selenium to use the latest chromedriver installed in my system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby gem `webdrivers` and it will take care of webdriver version required for your test suite. Just add below statement in your project (preferably in env.rb if you're using cucumber):

`require 'webdriver'`